# Sync view/data load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm going to perform 2 AJAX calls:

1. Load HTML partial template.
2. Load JSON data for template and render it into loaded template.

JSON should be loaded separate from template because user can trigger some kind of "refresh" action. Template can't be loaded on the first page load because there is tab control on the page and every tab should be loaded "on demand".

So let's say some `function loadData` was called. So I need to do the following:

1. If template is already loaded then GOTO step 3.
2. Send AJAX for template using `$().load` and AJAX for JSON data using `$.getJSON` **at the same time**. The fact is we can send both them together without waiting for template is loaded, am I right?
3. If JSON is loaded then check if template is already here. If so then render data into template. Else wait for template is loaded and then render data on success.

So I wonder what is the best practice for such activity? Is there any complete solution for it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use jQuery Deferreds (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to coordinate all this.

JS Code:

```
var templatePromise = null;

function loadData() {
    if (!templatePromise) {
        templatePromise = $.get('templateUrl');
    }

    var dataPromise = $.getJSON('dataUrl');

    $.when(templatePromise, dataPromise)
        .done(function (template, data) {

            // you have both template and data. 

        })
        .fail(function () {
            // either the template or the data failed to be fetched properly.
        });
}
```